# How can I show # instead of characters in input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have an `input` text (text box) in a php page whose `maxlength` attribute is 11. 
Basically, I use it for phone number. When the user enters a phone number, it will show as # symbols of all 11 characters and if the phone no < 11 show a message, if phone no > 11, user cannot type more characters. Note that on the textbox, the user can enter only numbers.

How do I do that?

Comment: How much of this functionality have you coded yourself already? Did you do the restrictions yet? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an standard Input type that is type="tel" but The **tel** type is currently supported only in **Safari 8**.

```
<input type="tel" name="usrtel">
```

But I suggest you to try this And this just accept the number with 11 Charecters:

```css
input:invalid{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{11}" name="tel" placeholder="Just phone Number"/>
```